# Lottery Program Problems

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently in progress of creating my second main C program. I've only just started to learn C and I've had a few problems, as well confusion on what to do next with this program.

The idea is to basically allow the user to enter in a desired amount of years, then the program simulates the lottery games played every week, depending on how many years they enter. Then inside the program, I want the two arrays to compare to each other and check for any numbers they both have at the same time. The lottery ticket on the user's end stays the same, which is set inside the array and of course, the random lottery numbers change every week.

The basics are done, I'm just having a few problems, as well as not knowing where to go in certain areas.

Problems:
"int weeks = year * 52" doesn't work, says the initializer element isn't constant.

When I return the get_lotto_draw, I just get a bunched up number, it's not seperated in anyway, so I'm not sure how to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h> //Alows input/output operations
#include <stdlib.h> //Standard utility operations

//Declaring Variables
int year;
char name[15];
char option;
int lotteryPlayer[] = {5,11,15,33,42,43};
int i;
int randomNums[49];
int *lotteryPtr = lotteryPlayer;
int *randomPtr = randomNums;
int weeks = 0;

void print_array(int *lotteryPtr);
int* get_lotto_draw(int *randomPtr);

//Main Method
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    start: //Start of program

    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\nProject: Jackpot Dreams ");
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");

   printf("\nWhat is your First Name?:> "); //Asks them for their choice
   scanf("%s", &name); //Reads the input

   printf("\nHow Many Years to Sleep?:> "); //Asks them for their choice
   scanf("%d", &year); //Reads the input
   weeks = year * 52;

   printf("\nOk %s, I will play the lottery for %d years!\n",name, year);
   sleep(1500);
   printf("Sweet Dreams %s, don't let the bed bugs bite", &name);
   sleep(1500);
   printf(". ");
   sleep(1500);
   printf(". ");
   sleep(1500);
   printf(".");
   sleep(2000);

   printf("%d", get_lotto_draw);
   system("PAUSE");
}

//Returns an array of six random lottery numbers 1-49
int* get_lotto_draw(int *randomPtr) 
{
    for (i=0 ; i<weeks ; i++)
       return randomNums;  
}

//Print out the content of an array
void print_array(int *lotteryPtr)
{
     printf("Hello");
}

//Returns number of matches between two arrays
int find_matches(int * lotteryPtr, int * randomPtr)
{

}
```

Update:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Alows input/output operations
#include <stdlib.h> //Standard utility operations

//Declaring Variables
int year;
char name[15];
char option;
int lotteryPlayer[] = {5,11,15,33,42,43};
int i;
int randomNums[49];
int *lotteryPtr = lotteryPlayer;
int *randomPtr = randomNums;
int weeks = 0;

void print_array(int *lotteryPtr);
int* get_lotto_draw(int *randomPtr);

//Main Method
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    start: //Start of program

    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\nProject: Jackpot Dreams ");
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");

   printf("\nWhat is your First Name?:> "); //Asks them for their choice
   scanf("%s", name); //Reads the input

   printf("\nHow Many Years to Sleep?:> "); //Asks them for their choice
   scanf("%d", &year); //Reads the input
   weeks = year * 52;

   printf("\nOk %s, I will play the lottery for %d years!\n",name, year);
   sleep(1500);
   printf("Sweet Dreams %s, don't let the bed bugs bite", &name);
   sleep(1500);
   printf(". ");
   sleep(1500);
   printf(". ");
   sleep(1500);
   printf(".");
   sleep(2000);

   printf("%d", get_lotto_draw(*randomPtr));
   system("PAUSE");
}

//Returns an array of six random lottery numbers 1-49
int* get_lotto_draw(int *randomPtr) 
{
    for (i=0 ; i<weeks ; i++)
       return randomNums;  
}

//Print out the content of an array
void print_array(int *lotteryPtr)
{
     printf("Hello");
}

//Returns number of matches between two arrays
int find_matches(int * lotteryPtr, int * randomPtr)
{

}
```

Comment: `"int weeks = year * 52" doesn't work, says the initializer element isn't constant.` `year` doesn't have a value yet (uninitialized).

Comment: Global variables cannot be initialized with other variables. Don't initialize `weeks. Instead, add `weeks = year * 52` after `scanf("%d", &year);`.

`get_lotto_draw()` is just broken. You are returning after the first iteration in the loop.

Comment: `i` is also uninitialized in `get_lotto_draw()`

Comment: Remember that in a for loop, the first is the initialization, the second is the comparison, and the third is the increment. Were you trying to write `for (i=0 ; i<weeks ; i++)` maybe?

Comment: I don't see where you filled `randomNums` with random numbers either, and you're accessing it wrong in `get_lotto_draw()`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` should be `scanf("%s", name);`. name is already a pointer: char a[] is equal to use char *a. In the case of char a[15] it will reserve memory, but that is other thing not related to the fact that an array variable is itself a pointer.

Comment: Please, do _not_ modify your initial question. Make an update after your own text with your final source code version :)

Comment: get_lotto_draw()  returns a pointer(as array), so maybe `printf("%d", &get_lotto_draw);` should be something like printf("%d", get_lotto_draw **(missing parameter)** **[index]** );

Comment: Sorry to just throw those comments at you but you have some fundamental problems in the code. Hopefully our comments will help get you on the right track ;)

Comment: So how do I make my random numbers array actually hold six random numbers between 1-49?

Comment: Something like `for (i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) randomNums[i] = rand()%49 + 1 ;`, but I have never used `rand()`. Search about `rand()` and `srand()`. By the way, then `randomNums` should have a size for 6 elements? You have it for 49 elements (not values betweet 1-49).

Comment: With the approch of Alfonso, you'd also need to check at each iteration that the random number you pick is not already contained in the array (I assume you want random numbers without repetition).

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing mostly from the comments, there are a few problems with your code.

`int weeks = year * 52;` results in an error because `year` hasn't been initialized. Change it to `int weeks = 0;`, and then put `weeks = year * 52` at the beginning of your main function.

You don't need the `start:` label at the beginning of your program, unless for some reason you want to go back there using a `goto`, which is usually considered bad practice.

`printf("%d", get_lotto_draw);` prints the address of `get_lotto_draw` as a decimal ("%d"), you need to make it `get_lotto_draw(args)` to get the return value of `get_lotto_draw`.

system("PAUSE"), runs the command PAUSE on the shell. I don't know if this will pause the current program, but if you don't want the program to exit, a loop will do instead.

```
while (1) {}
```

Your implementation of `get_lotto_draw` doesn't do what you think it does. What you are doing now is just returning `randomNums`, what you want to do is generate a random number between 1 and 49. To do this you should first generate a random number, and mod it by 48 and add one. This will get you a random number between 1 and 49. `srand(time(NULL)); int r = rand();` will generate a random number, and `r %= 48; r += 1;` will mod it by 48 and add one. You can then do this for each iteration of that for loop, and create an array with the values. The array that you will return will have to be `malloc`'d.

```
int get_lotto_draw() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* rv = malloc(sizeof(int) * 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        rv[i] = (rand() % 48) + 1;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Your `find_matches` function is also unimplemented. Simply iterating through the arrays to find matches should suffice.

```
int find_matches(int* a, int* b) {
    int matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[i]) {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Lastly, for your `print_array` function, you again just need to iterate through the list of lottery numbers, and print each one.

```
void print_array(int* arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", arr[5]);
    printf("\n"); // remove this if you don't want a newline at the end.
}
```